# PDE $u_x+u_y=1-u$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am given the following

$$
\begin{cases}
u_x+u_y=1-u, x>0\\
u(x,x+x^2)=sinx\\
\end{cases}
$$

I am trying to solve it using method of characteristics.

So I got the following equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
x_t=1\Rightarrow x(t,s)=t+f_1(s)\\
y_t=1\Rightarrow x(t,s)=t+f_2(s)\\
u_t=1-u
\end{cases}
$$

But the third equation is again a pde

Comment: Yes but $u=u(t,s)$ and you can see it as $u=\tilde{u}(t)$ since there is no explicit appearence of $s$, hence $u_t=\tilde{u}'$ so you can solve the ODE in the classical way. Then as in the first two equations you've solved the dependency on $s$ appears with the initial data $f_3(s)=\sin{s}$

Comment: @Dadeslam So I get $u(t,s)=t-ut+f_3(s)$?

Comment: I did not do the full computation but I think rewriting the equation as $(e^tu)_t = e^t$ you get $u(t,s)=1+e^{-t}(\sin{(s)}-1)$

Comment: By the way I've just seen in the PDE there was $u+1$ and not $1-u$ so we need to rewrite it as $(ue^{-t})=e^{-t}$ hence the result is different

Comment: @Dadeslam Yes, sorry it is $1-u$

Comment: Ah okok so it should be correct what I've written above, the problem is then to invert the relation and hence write $u$ as $u=u(s(x,y),t(x,y))$ by inverting the transformation and you can conclude

Answer (score 2):

The problem reduces to solve the following system: $$
\dfrac{dx}{1}=\dfrac{dy}{1}=\dfrac{du}{1-u}.
$$
Thus, solving the first equality we obtain $$
x=y+c_1 \quad \implies \quad x-y=c_1.
$$
On the other hand, solving the equation for $u$ we have $$
dx=\dfrac{du}{1-u} \quad \implies \quad -\log(1-u)=x+c_2 \quad \implies \quad u=1-e^{-x+\tilde{c}_2}.
$$
Making $\tilde{c}_2=-c_2=\phi(c_1)$, where $\phi$ is a function to be determined according to the boundary conditions, we obtain $$
u(x,y)=1-e^{-x+\phi(x-y)}.
$$
I let you to find $\phi$ by replacing $u(x,y)$ into the boundary conditions. Notice that this is correct since $u$ solves the PDE. In fact, the left-hand side is $$
u_x=e^{-x+\phi}-\phi'e^{-x+\phi},\quad u_y=\phi'e^{-x+\phi} \quad \implies u_x+u_y=e^{-x+\phi}
$$
On the other hand, the right-hand side is $$
1-u=1-\big(1-e^{-x+\phi}\big)=e^{-x+\phi}.
$$

Comment: Why can we set $-c_2=\phi(c_1)$?

Comment: Kind of general procedure. Once you solve the equation for $x$ and $y$ you will get an integration constant. Then, after solving the equation for the unknown $u$ (and hence obtaining a second integration constant), you replace the latter constant for an arbitrary function of the first one $\widetilde{c}_2=\phi(c_1)$.

Comment: This is related to the fact that when you integrate (in one variable) a multi-dimensional function, you obtain an integration constant depending on the remaining variables (i.e. an arbitrary function depending on the remaining variables): for instance $$ \int \partial_y f(x,y)dy=f(x,y)+c(x).$$ I recommend you to take a look in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics

Comment: I see, So we got $u(x,y)=1-\phi(x-y)e^{-x}$ using the boundary condition we get $sinx=1-\phi(-x^2)e^{-x}\Rightarrow e^x(-sinx+1)=\phi(-x^2)$

Comment: Looks okay for me

Comment: But shouldn't we find $\phi$ explicitly? for example $\phi(x)=x^2+1$?

Comment: Do a change of variables. You already have $\phi$ explicitly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107048/discussion-between-newhere-and-sharik).